# Spring Boot @RestController accept @RequestBody of different structure bean object dynamically and validate the request

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

In Spring Boot I am trying to create a `@RestController` which should accepts different structure of `@RequestBody` and validate the bean using `@Valid` annotation.

I checked couple of options like making request body `String` , `Map` and `JSON` structure but in these options I am not able to use `javax.validation.Valid` annotation.

My request body schema are given below

**Schema 1**

```
{
  "type": "type1",
  "message": "String value"
}
```

**Schema 2**

```
{
  "type": "type2",
  "message": [
    {
      "key1": "value",
      "key2": "value"
    },
    {
      "key1": "value",
      "key2": "value"
    }
  ]
}
```

Based of `type` key in the request `message` key is holding different structure value. In **Schema 1**  `message` key have `String` value and in **Schema 2**  `message` key have `List of Object` as a value

I am looking for the best approach to handle above scenario with bean validation enabled with `@Valid` annotation

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it at bean level.

like

```
@NotNull
@Size(min=2, max=30)
private String name;
```

refer below links

https://spring.io/guides/gs/validating-form-input/

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-bean-validation

for switching from one bean to another you can use switch case or add @Valid in the service layer instead of rest controller(API) layer after you get the bean type.

```
public methodName(@Valid ObjectName object){
.....
}
```

In Bean, you can declare

datatype type;

@valid
datatype message;

then you do it same in message named bean.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible using default spring provided implementation. You should do it by yourself by creating a custom class which accepts both types (String, List of Object) object, then you should write your own annotation to validate this.